# Crud application with NetBeans and Oracle 10g

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, oracle10g, crud

I was trying to generate a CRUD application with NetBeans 7.4. The connection with the database worked fine, i created a master/detail form etc..
The problem is when I generated the interface, two classes were created:

- one with the name of the table (which is expected), and
- one with the name of the Primary key constraint

On the interface, only one column was created(with the name of the primary key).

Question is: How can I overcome this problem? Is this normal?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Talk is cheap, show us the code :)

Comment: well, i didn't write any code. I just followed this short tutorial that shows how to generate a CRUD app with netbeans.. :http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BXQg_guFL2k

Comment: probably the problem is that my table has a "complex " primary key, made of two columns..